# converting int to string using recursion

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I know in python we can easily convert an int to string with str().  I would like to convert int to string using recursion and not using str().  I came up with the following which appears to work but looks overly complicated.  Is there a cleaner, elegant, more efficient algorithm?

```
def intTOstring(n,text=""):
    if n == 0:
        return text
    elif n < 10 and n > 0:
        return text + chr(n+48)
    else:
        x = n
        i = 0
        while(x >= 10):
            x = x // 10
            i += 1            
        n = n - x*10**i        
        text = text + chr(x+48)
        if n < 10**(i-1):
            text = text + chr(48)
        return intTOstring(n,text)
    
print(intTOstring(125))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do:

```py
def int_to_string(n):
    i, j = n // 10, n % 10
    return (int_to_string(i) if i > 0 else "") + chr(j + 48)


s = int_to_string(125)
print(s, type(s))
```

Prints:

```
125 <class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the modulus to simplify your function

```
def intToString(n):
    if n < 10:
        return chr(n % 10 + 48)
    return intToString(n // 10) + chr(n % 10 + 48)
```

Comment: what about `n=0`? :)

Comment: you're right ,  Andrej's solution is better

Comment: edit: fixed for `n=0`

Comment: nice! or `def int_to_string(n): return ("" if n < 10 else int_to_string(n // 10)) + chr(48 + n % 10)`